# AutoCompleteTextView select item retuns IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, autocompletetextview

I am using an `AutoCompleteTextView` which is loading from server database. It's populating data but when I select the item it is throwing `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0`. I am sharing some of my code.

MainActivity.java

```
 autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.at_search);

        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                adapter = new AutoSearchAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.search_row);//custom adapter class
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(450);
                autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {

                User item = (User)adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                if(item != null) {

                    Log.d("Adapter","Selected item:"+item.getUsername());

                }
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Adapter

```
    public class AutoSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> implements Filterable {

    int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<User> mData;

    private URLConnection ucon;
    private Context context;

    public AutoSearchAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId){
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

     //   this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        mData = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public User getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.search_row, null);
        }
        User o = mData.get(position);
        if (o != null) {

            final TextView catID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_hello);
            //   TextView reviewCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reviewCount);

            final String text = o.getUsername();
            catID.setText(o.getUsername());
            //   reviewCount.setText(o.getReviewCount());
        }
        return v;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if(constraint != null){
                    try {
                        // A method that queries a web API, parses the data and returns an ArrayList<User>
                        mData = autoComplete(constraint.toString());
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        Log.e("myException", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object
                    filterResults.values = mData;
                    filterResults.count = mData.size();

                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class User {

    public String user_name = "";

    public void setUsername(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return user_name;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                       Process: com.example.ashfaque.autocompletetext, PID: 30429                                                                                        java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0                                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)                                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)                                                                                             at adapter.AutoSearchAdapter.getItem(AutoSearchAdapter.java:61)                                                                                             at com.example.ashfaque.autocompletetext.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:62)                                                                                            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:906)                                                                                              at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
                                                                                           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1202)                                                                                            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)                                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3081)                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3947)                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where are you setting your adapter in your AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: onTextChanged method

Comment: why are you putting a empty arraylist inside your adapter?

Comment: Please suggest me what to do

Comment: sure, you will answer your question

Comment: Just to create an array object, I am putting an empty arraylist inside adapter and mData = autoComplete(constraint.toString()); is assigning arraylist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145127/discussion-between-ipl10-and-luiz-fernando-salvaterra).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830